# Splitting pl/sql substitution variable at whitespace

Tags: sql, oracle

I'm trying to use an anonymous block to have a user enter 'Hello World' and then have the console output Hello then World.

```
DECLARE
 user_text VARCHAR2(20) := &userInput;
 start_position VARCHAR2(20) := INSTR(user_text, ' ');
 extracted_string VARCHAR2(20) := SUBSTR(user_text, start_position);

BEGIN

DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE(TRIM(extracted_string));

END;
```

The above code only outputs 'World'.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It only outputs "World" because thats exactly what you coded.

If you also want the first word, you need to add something like this :

```
DECLARE
   -- rest of your code
   first_word VARCHAR2(20) := SUBSTR(user_text, 0, start_position);
BEGIN
   DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE(TRIM(first_word));
   -- rest of your code
END;
```

Answer (score 1):

Its not clear what you are trying to achieve but if just want that for input `Hello World`, `World Hello` should be displayed, then you also need to get start word of string before space as below.

```
DECLARE
 user_text VARCHAR2(20) := 'Hello World';
 start_position VARCHAR2(20) := INSTR(user_text, ' ');
 start_word_of_string varchar(20) := SUBSTR(user_text,0,start_position); 
 extracted_string VARCHAR2(20) := SUBSTR(user_text, start_position);

BEGIN

DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE(extracted_string || ' ' || start_word_of_string);

END;
```

**Result:**

```
World Hello
```

**[DEMO](http://rextester.com/PFV12640)**